# Access websphere variables of Server from Development machine

Tags: java, environment-variables, websphere

First of all, I know how to read Custom properties of Web sphere if its in my local machine as

```
system.getproperty("")
```

But, now the web sphere is the server and there are some variables defined. How can I access from my machine?

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You could expose them with a simple servlet or JAX-RS endpoint and access them over HTTP.

Comment: I got your point. But, unfortunately in the server, I can only access, but not expose

Comment: Access via what?

Comment: My application runs in ABC machine and the data base is in DEF machine. Web sphere is defined in DEF machine and the libraries are defined in it. I cannot create any servlet in DEF machine or anything which can expose the details. Because Tomorrow it will go to production with other IP. In each IP, the tables names are a bit different, but keys remain same in custom properties